# Write a custom django validation function

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-validation

I have a field named bar i need to write a validation function to validate this bar in django what conditions can i apply to this and how should my function be?

**Note**:Please dont share link of django validators

**models.py**

```
class Model:
    bar = models.CharField('Bar', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: what are you trying to do? bar has no semantic by itself

Answer (score 1):

You can define a function that will validate the value and raise a [**`ValidationError`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/validation/#raising-validationerror) in case the condition is not valid, so:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def validate_bar(value):
    if not some-condition:
        raise ValidationError('Bar should satisfy a certain condition', code='some_code')
```

then you add this function to the `validators` of that field

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    bar = models.CharField('Bar', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, validators=[validate_bar])
```

note that validators will only run in `ModelForm`s, `ModelAdmin`s, `ModelSerializer`s, etc. Not by the Django ORM for performance reasons.

Comment: Thanks for the answer i know the above structure but i need that some condition with respect to above field what can be the conditions is what is not striking for me

Comment: @itriedit: well the `some-condition` should be a Python expression that works with the value. For example `value is not None and value.startswith('foo')`.

Answer (score -1):

```
def val(v):
    if v is not None:
        try:
            if len(v) <= 255:
                return True
        except ValidationError:
            return False
```

does this work ? with balnk = True ,null = True and max_length

Comment: the validator should *not* return `True` or `False`, but raise a `Validation` error in case it is invalid. Furthermore Django will automatically validate the length of a string, so that validation is *not* necessary.l